# ActionScript - Determine If Value is Class Constant

Tags: actionscript-3, constants

i'd like to throw an argument error if a particular function doesn't work without a passed value that also happens to be a public constant of the class containing the function.

is there anyway to determine if a class owns a public constant instead of having to iterate thru all of them?

something like this:

```
public static const HALIFAX:String = "halifax";
public static const MONTREAL:String = "montreal";
public static const TORONTO:String = "toronto";

private var cityProperty:String;

public function set city(value:String):void
     {
     if (!this.hasConstant(value))
        throw new ArgumentError("set city value is not applicable.");

     cityProperty = value;
     }

public function get city():Strig
     {
     return cityProperty;
     }
```

currently, for this functionality i have to write the city setter function like this:

```
public function set city(value:String):void
     {
     if (value != HALIFAX && value != MONTREAL && value != TORONTO)
        throw new ArgumentError("set city value is not applicable.");

     cityProperty = value;
     }
```

is this the only way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why don't you use a better method for this. Keep a private static array of the city names, and check if the city exists within the array?

Comment: i'd prefer to keep code hinting available by using constants.

Comment: sure, but if i have to write out the constants twice i might as well just write them all again in the conditional of the city setter.

Comment: The difference is that you could iterate through them in multiple functions. The DRY ideal is to never repeat yourself, but in this case it's better for performance to repeat yourself once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you use reflections:

```
private var type:Class;
private var description:XML;

private function hasConstant (str : String ) : Boolean 
{
    if (description == null) 
    {
        type = getDefinitionByName (getQualifiedClassName (this)) as Class;
        description = describeType (type);      
    }
    for each ( var constant:XML in description.constant) 
    {
        if (type[constant.@name] == str) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that for this to work, all constants must always be String objects declared `public static const`.

Comment: isn't this overcomplicating things a bit?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve.  I can think of a number of cases where this would be useful, for example when trying to determine if an event code string belongs to a certain type of event.

Comment: My understanding is that anything involving reflection in ActionScript has a severe performance hit. If that is the case, I'd be careful about implementing this on functions that are used frequently, and where performance is a greater consideration than bullet-proofing your code.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for an answer to this question myself and found it annoying that `hasOwnProperty()` did not work for static properties.  Turns out though, that if you cast your class to a `Class` object, it does work.

Here's an example:

```
public final class DisplayMode
{
  public static const one:   String = "one";
  public static const two:   String = "two";
  public static const three: String = "three";

  public static function isValid(aDisplayMode: String): Boolean {
    return Class(DisplayMode).hasOwnProperty(aDisplayMode);
  }
}
```

I owe this solution to jimmy5804 from [this discussion](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=165627), so hats off to him.

Comment: It should be noted that this only works if the constant value is exactly the same as the constant name. Ie: `public static const ENUM_ONE:String = 'one';` will NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use bracket notation to do this. For example:

```
var foo:Sprite = new Sprite();
foo.rotation = 20;
trace( foo["x"], foo["rotation"]); // traces "0 20"
```

or more specific to your case:

```
var bar:String = "rotation";
trace( foo[bar] ); // traces "20"
```

The only thing you have to look out for here, is that the bracket accessor will throw a ReferenceError if you ask for an object property that isn't there, such as:

```
trace ( foo["cat"] ); // throws ReferenceError
```

But it will not throw if you are asking for a static property:

```
trace ( Sprite["cat"] ); // traces "undefined"
```

So in your case you might try:

```
if ( this[value] == undefined ) {
    throw new ArgumentError("set city value is not applicable.");
}
```

---

EDIT: 
Sorry, I was confusing the const's names with their values.

For this to work on your problem you would have to make the String value the same as the const's name, so for example:

```
public static const HALIFAX:String = "HALIFAX";
```

then you could use the query as described above and it would give you the desired result.

Comment: He is trying to determine whether a value is equal to a constant of the class.  How does accessing instance variables by name solve this?

Comment: hummm... ok, but what if i have other public strings that aren't constants and should throw an error if set as the city?

Comment: @weltraumpirat you are completely right, I misunderstood the problem. But as it so happens, this solution would work if you set the Strings value to be their name. So for example if you had `const HALIFAX:String = "HALIFAX";` then you could just ask `if ( this[value] == undefined )` and it would give you the desired result.