# Get all static variables in a class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, static, properties

I have this ObjectType class which is a class to help me do something like this:

```
object.type = ObjectType.TWO

//ObjectType.as
package
{
    public class ObjectType
    {
        public static var ONE:String = "one";
        public static var TWO:String = "two";
        public static var THREE:String = "three";

        public function ObjectType()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Let's suppose I'm creating a new class and I need a property named type. In that property set function I want to make sure that it's value is one of the ObjectType variables. How can I achieve this?

```
public function set type(value:String):void 
{
    for (var o:Object in ObjectType) {
        if (value == o)
            this._type = value;     
        } else {
            //error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionScript - Determine If Value is Class Constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266655/actionscript-determine-if-value-is-class-constant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not performance aware but without modifying anything you can use [describeType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) function to check the static field and get the value back:

```
function valueInClass(clazz:Class, value:*):Boolean {
 return describeType(clazz).variable.(clazz[@name.toString()] == value).length() != 0
}

public function set type(value:String):void 
{
 if (valueInClass(ObjectType, value)) {
  this._type = value;     
 } else {
  //error
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the second code example you presented doesn't work...

I think it is because you're using the *for in* loop a little bit wrong.

```
for (var blah:String in somewhere){
    // blah represents a KEY of the somewhere object
    // to get the value of this key, use:
    var theValue = somewhere[blah];
}
```

It's the *for each* loop that loops through the values. But for now I'll use the *for in*.

Also, it's not `in ObjectType`, but rather in the class' prototype, that is `in ObjectType.prototype`.

So, to fix this:

```
for (var o:* in ObjectType.prototype) {
    if (value == ObjectType.prototype[o])
        this._type = value;     
    } else {
        //error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using reflection.

A similar question was asked just a few days ago, you should be able to use the same solution, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266655/actionscript-determine-if-value-is-class-constant/5267416#5267416).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know what reflection was until now :P

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that while the the accepted answer is right, it's also really slow. Not something that you want to do a lot. There are three simpler solutions.

**One:** Check the value itself:

```
public function set type(value:String):void 
{
    if( value != ObjectType.ONE && value != ObjectType.TWO && value != ObjectType.THREE )
        return;
}
```

Obviously, the more constants you have the check the harder this becomes.

**Two:** Use ints as your constants

Change your ObjectType class to use ints:

```
public class ObjectType
{
    public static var NONE:int = 0;
    public static var ONE:int = 1;
    public static var TWO:int = 2;
    public static var THREE:int = 3;
    public static var TOTAL:int = 4;
}
```

Notice the `NONE` and `TOTAL` in there? This makes it easy to check if your value is in the right range:

```
public function set type(value:int):void 
{
    if( value <= ObjectType.NONE || value >= ObjectType.TOTAL )
        return;
}
```

You can add more values as needed and you just need to update `TOTAL` and it'll still work. This needs each value to be in order though.

**Three:** Use Enums

While Flash has no in-build class for enums, there's a lot of solutions available. Check our the `Enum` class from Scott Bilas: http://scottbilas.com/blog/ultimate-as3-fake-enums/

Using this as your base class your `ObjectType` class becomes:

```
public final class ObjectType extends Enum
{

    { initEnum( ObjectType ); } // static ctor

    public static const ONE:ObjectType = new ObjectType;
    public static const TWO:ObjectType = new ObjectType;
    public static const THREE:ObjectType = new ObjectType;

}
```

And your check now becomes:

```
public function set type(value:ObjectType):void 
{
    ...
}
```

Here, your setter now becomes type safe and will throw errors if anything other than an `ObjectType` is used.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if using an ENUM type of check you should check for the *constants* property, not *variables* as showin in the example here:
[ActionScript - Determine If Value is Class Constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266655/actionscript-determine-if-value-is-class-constant/5267416#5267416)